# How to get weights from layer of neural network that is defined as a class object in Pytorch?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I am developing something on top of an already existing framework of code, and I am having some trouble extracting weights from a neural network defined as a class. Code below

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class Solver:
    class Head(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, base):
            super().__init__()
            self.base = base
            self.last_layer = nn.Linear(100, 10)

        def forward(self, x):
            x = self.base(x)
            x = self.last_layer(x)
            return x

    def __init__(self, bases, HeadClass=None):
        self.base = bases
        if HeadClass:
            self.head = self.Head(self.base)
        else:
            self.head = self.Head(self.base)
        print('Head Class:',self.head)

class Full_Solver:
    class Base(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.linear_1 = nn.Linear(1, 100)
            self.linear_2 = nn.Linear(100, 100)
            self.linear_3 = nn.Linear(100, 100)

        def forward(self, x):
            x = self.linear_1(x)
            x = torch.tanh(x)
            x = self.linear_2(x)
            x = torch.tanh(x)
            x = self.linear_3(x)
            x = torch.tanh(x)
            return x

    def __init__(self, BaseClass=Base()):
        self.base = BaseClass
        print('Base model:',self.base)
        print('Base model type:',type(self.base))

        solver_1 = Solver(self.base)
        print('Full model:',solver_1)
        print('Full model type:',type(solver_1))


xx = Full_Solver()
```

In the `Full_Solver` class, I am defining a Base Neural Network, which will add a Head based on some conditions in the `Solver` class (I have left out all the conditions for sake of brevity). When I do `print('Full model:',solver_1)`, the output I am getting is `Full model: <__main__.Solver object at 0x7f83a82e9cd0>`. **How do I extract the output weights from this class object?** (Assume that I just want to extract the randomly assigned weights from this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it would be `print('Full model:',solver_1.head.last_layer.weight)`